# RayTest failing when there is a transform

Tags: bulletphysics

I have a problem getting ray testing working in bullet physics. 
The raytest only works for objects which have an identity transform. If there is any translation, then the ray test is calculated wrong. This is the code:
[code]

```
            btTransform trans;
            trans.setIdentity();
            trans.setFromOpenGLMatrix(matrix.m);
            btDefaultMotionState* motionState = new btDefaultMotionState(trans);
            btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo rbInfo(
                0, motionState, m_pVertexBuffer->GetBulletShape(), btVector3(0,0,0));
            btRigidBody* body = new btRigidBody(rbInfo);      
            g_physics.GetWorld()->addRigidBody(body);
    ....
        g_physics.GetWorld()->updateAabbs();
        g_physics.GetWorld()->computeOverlappingPairs();
        btVector3 btStart(x1, y1, z1);
        btVector3 btEnd(x2, y2, z2);
        btCollisionWorld::ClosestRayResultCallback ray(btStart, btEnd);


// Perform raycast
    g_physics.GetWorld()->rayTest(btStart, btEnd, ray);
    if (ray.hasHit()) 
    {
        btEnd = ray.m_hitPointWorld;
    }
```

[/code]
Now, my game is using the z-axis as up, but that shouldn't be a problem as the ray is also entered as z up.

Comment: I'd try turning debug lines on, to check the bullet object is where you expect.

Comment: I got it working now. It was just a stupid bug in my code :-O. Thanks for your help - the debug draw helped.